# egrep statement with '@' and '&'

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I am working on a shell script program where i am encountering `@` and `&`.

```
/bin/egrep -c '(@ sMAD:|& MAD :)' $File
```

Could you please tell me what `egrep` is doing  here. I understand that that we are getting the count of number of lines but this regex part is really confusing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is looking for either `@ sMAD:` or `& MAD :` in the file referred by `$File` and counting how many lines satisfy this condition.

```
egrep -c '(@ sMAD:|& MAD :)' $File
       ^   ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^
       |      |    or this
       |   either this
       count lines that contain
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
@ sMAD: can match & MAD : everything in the same line  # match 1
& MAD : also does                                      # match 2
but & MAD : is another thing                           # match 3
```

And now let's run the command:

```
$ egrep -c '(@ sMAD:|& MAD :)' a
3
```

Comment: so '@' and  '&' here has no special meaning and are instead treated part of the string for pattern matching ?